# Binary variable in regression model (interview question)

Tags: regression, categorical-data, linear-model, interview

I got this question, it may be easy but for some reason for me is not:

you are given a binary variable $b\in [0,1]$, that has no predictive power on $y$, but has some on $X$. How would you use it to improve the performance of a regression model $y=\beta X+\epsilon$?"

Any thoughts ? Thank you.

Comment: I would ask for clarification on what is meant by having no predictive power on $y$ and some predictive power on $X$.

Comment: I agree, that is a thing that wasn't so clear. I wouldn't believe that if X is actually able to explain y in a linear model, then b has no role on explaining y.

Comment: If $b$ has predictive power on $X$ that has predictive power on $y$, then should'nt $b$ have predictive power on $y$ ?

Comment: That is exactly what intuition would suggest me, but I am bad at linear regression in first place ..

Answer (score 0):

Frame challenge: this is a question to test your ability to deal with a question from a client that uses poor phrasing.

Probably most people in technical consulting roles find themselves dealing with this. My approach has been to keep asking follow-up questions, either to reveal misunderstanding from that client that lead to me getting an opportunity to teach, or getting the client to rephrase the question in a way that makes sense. I'll give an example of how I could see such a conversation going.

> Client: "We have this other variable, $b$, that has no ability to predict $y$ but does have some ability to predict $X$. How can we use b to make a better prediction of y than we get from $y = X\beta+\epsilon?$

> Consultant: What do you mean that $b$ has no ability to predict $y$ but does have ability to predict $X$?

> Client: When we run the regression on $b$, so $y = \beta b + \epsilon$, we get an insignificant $F$-test with $p = 0.06$, but we get $p=0.04$ when we run $X = \beta b +\epsilon$.

At that point, I might see this as an ANCOVA-style problem, where the effect of $X$ on $y$ might wash out the effect of $b$ on $y$ (which is exactly why ANCOVA makes use of the covariate), even if $b$ has an effect on $y$.